# Info from xml to c# with irregular xml

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, xmlreader

I need to get info from an XML-file in C#.

Here is some fragments from the XML.

```
<Surface id="su-62" surfaceType="InteriorWall">
    <Name>S-3-7-I-W-62</Name>
    <AdjacentSpaceId spaceIdRef="sp-3-TUIN">
    </AdjacentSpaceId>
    <AdjacentSpaceId spaceIdRef="sp-7-huizen">
    </AdjacentSpaceId>
    <CADObjectId>Basic Wall: _omgevingsmuur [184610]</CADObjectId>
</Surface>
...
<Surface id="su-63" surfaceType="ExteriorWall">
    <Name>N-4-E-W-63</Name>
    <AdjacentSpaceId spaceIdRef="sp-4-onthaal">
    </AdjacentSpaceId>
    <Opening id="su-63-op-1" openingType="NonSlidingDoor">
    </Opening>
    <CADObjectId>Basic Wall: _detentiemuur [193431]</CADObjectId>
</Surface>  
...
<Surface id="su-282" surfaceType="Shade">
    <Name>X-S-282</Name>
    <CADObjectId>Basic Roof: Generic - 400mm [190976]</CADObjectId>
</Surface>
```

As you see there are some surfaces that don't have all the info others have.
I have to know which surfaces are adjacent to which space and if there is an opening or not.

(The ultimate goal is to make an 2d array where you can see which SPACE is adjacent to which SPACE and another array to see if the have a joined opening.)

Comment: Use LinqToXML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: What information are you trying to retrieve from the xml fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have .NET 3.5 or greater, than this is a good use for [LINQ2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

You can write a query that will grab the associated areas an identify which space are adjacent to each other.

```
// Load your XML File into an XDocument object
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

// this is your query, in the end result with my a Dictionary with the Surface 
//  Id attribute as the key and the AdjacentSpaceId as the value
var result = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("AdjacentSpaceId")
              select new
              {
                  SurfaceId = (String)x.Parent.Attribute("id"),
                  SurfaceName = (String)x.Parent.Element("Name"),
                  AdjacentSpace = (String)x
              }).GroupBy(sp => sp.SurfaceId)
                .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key,
                              grp => grp.Select(value => value.AdjacentSpace));
```

If you are unfamiliar with any of the LINQ varients, I will attempt to explain the query in a bit more detail.  The local field containing your query results is just called `results`.  The `var` type is another .NET 3.5 addition that tells the compiler to identify the type by the right side of the expression.  In this case, `result` will be a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<String>>`.

In the first line of the query:

```
from x in xDoc.Descendants("AdjacentSpaceId")
```

You are basically telling LINQ to iterate through all nodes in the XML called `AdjacentSpaceId`.  It doesn't matter where these nodes are located or what the parent nodes are called.  The `Descendants()` method in LINQ can be very powerful for this reason as it means you don't need to know the exact XML Path to a particular node to select it, you just need the name (see my note at the end)

The next lines of the query are defining exactly what you want to return from the query:

```
  select new
  {
      SurfaceId = (String)x.Parent.Attribute("id"),
      SurfaceName = (String)x.Parent.Element("Name"),
      AdjacentSpace = (String)x
  })
```

All LINQ queries using this syntax must have a `select` statement (there is also a method syntax that can be used instead of or in addition too that doesn't need a select necessarily, but this syntax is easier to learn in my opinion).

In the select clause, you are basically defining a new [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) that has 3 properties, `SurfaceId`, `SurfaceName`, and `AdjacentSpace`.  I'll explain one of the assignments and it should let you understand all of them:

```
SurfaceId = (String)x.Parent.Attribute("id")
```

In this line, `x` refers to the initial line of the LINQ query where you were iterating all of your `AdjacentSpaceId` nodes, so `x` is of type `XElement`.

The `Parent` property of `x` is going to select the parent node, in this case `Surface`.  (NOTE: If your root node in your XML happens to be called `AdjacentSpaceId`, then this line is going to throw an exception since the parent of a root node will be null, but seems to be a safe assumption that it won't be a problem in this case).  The `Parent` property on `XElement` is also going to be another `XElement`.

The next part is the `Attribute` method of `XElement`, and you are selecting the first attribute of node called `id`.

So effectively you are selecting the `id` attribute of all parent nodes to each `AdjacentSpaceId` nodes.

And lastly, I am casting this to a String.  There is a `Value` property that can be used instead, but my personal preference is to cast to a String because if the `Attribute("id")` method fails (which could happen if there is no attribute called "id"), calling the `Value` property will throw an exception, whereas casting to a string will just return null in these cases.

The other parts of this select clause are virtually the same.

The rest of this query are effectively separate queries.  I just chained them together, but they could easily be broken out and put on their own.

The next piece:

```
GroupBy(sp => sp.SurfaceId)
```

is grouping the result of your LINQ query by the `SurfaceId` property.  This is a key step because it sounds like you want to know where spaces are adjacent to each surface and this will effectively group all of the adjacent spaces together by the surface.

If you aren't familiar, `sp => sp.SurfaceId` is a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for creating anonymous functions or delegates quickly and easily.

And the final piece will take your grouped results and convert them into something more usable, usually a `Dictionary<>`, or in this case a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<String>>`

```
ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key,
             grp => grp.Select(value => value.AdjacentSpace));
```

Just one side note about the `Descendants()` extension method for Linq-to-Xml objects, while it can be very useful as I mentioned above, it can also be very dangerous.  When you have multiple nodes in the same XML with the same name but with different purposes or in different parents of the tree, `Descendants()` will return ALL objects.  If you only want to return *some* of the nodes matching a specific name, you need to filter it down first by using the `Element()` or `Elements()` extension methods first to select the proper parent node, then you can safely call `Descendants()`.